# Difference between the two KiTTY (PuTTY client) versions found on GitHub?

Tags: ssh

So looking KiTTY up (PuTTY fork), two versions with two separate GitHub pages come up:

- http://www.9bis.net/kitty/#!pages/download.md
- https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/kittens/ssh/
- https://github.com/cyd01/KiTTY
- https://github.com/kovidgoyal/kitty

What is the difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The other program is not a fork of PuTTY at all, it is an independently developed terminal emulator (for Linux) that's *just* a terminal emulator without any built-in SSH support.

KiTTY, terminal emulator and SSH client for Windows (PuTTY fork):

- Website: `http://www.9bis.net/kitty/`
- Source code repository: `https://github.com/cyd01/KiTTY`

kitty, terminal emulator for Linux using X11/Wayland:

- Website: `https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/`
- Source code repository: `https://github.com/kovidgoyal/kitty`